# doveadm search query with all Flag -A

Tags: dovecot, mailbox

I can search old mails for single user:

```
doveadm search -u 'user@mydomain.tld' mailbox Trash savedbefore 180d
```

returns results

```
f35jv2jh35vj2v5jh2v53…. 31
f35jv2jh35vj2v5jh2v53…. 42
…
```

The same search for all users return nothing (no output):

```
doveadm search -A mailbox Trash savedbefore 180d
```

I receive no output, no errors...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to setup two variables to make the [`-A` option](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man1/doveadm-search.1.html) work:

> **-A**: When  using  the LDAP userdb module, make sure that the *iterate_attrs* and *iterate_filter* settings in `/etc/dovecot/dovecot-ldap.conf.ext` match your LDAP  schema. Otherwise doveadm(1) will be unable to iterate over all users.

Example configuration in `dovecot-ldap.conf.ext` file:

```
# For using doveadm -A:
iterate_attrs = =user=%{ldap:uid}
iterate_filter = (objectClass=posixAccount)
```

Source: [Dovecot Wiki: Userdb LDAP](https://wiki.dovecot.org/AuthDatabase/LDAP/Userdb)